# An OpenGL backend for displaying a framebuffer of an emulator

Tags: c, graphics, opengl, emulator

#### Motivation

I'm making an emulator. It has its own software framebuffer of size 320x240. Each frame is prepared internally from the emulator, and I just need a way to display it on a window, scaled to the window size while maintaining the ratio (with black bars on each side if necessary).

My first try was using `SetDIBitsToDevice` from the Windows API, and it worked well. The problem was making it run on Linux, where you can use `XPutImage` (X11), `XShmPutImage` (MIT-SHM), or maybe even Wayland. There were enough problems for each of those options, and the documentation was also confusingly written. For ease of development, I then tried SDL as a cross-platform layer. They provide similar functionality through `SDL_GetWindowSurface`/`SDL_UpdateWindowSurface`, but this calls `XPutImage` or `XShmPutImage` behind. `XShmPutImage` is nice, but it doesn't run on Wayland. `XPutImage` is slow compared to `SetDIBitsToDevice` or `BitBlt` on Windows. Another problem is that SDL doesn't guarantee the pixel format of the window surface, although this isn't a problem if I'm only targeting Windows and Linux.

SDL has a renderer abstraction that can do either hardware or software rendering depending on the platform. One problem I found is that it runs a DirectX renderer by default on Windows, and this chokes when running on a Virtual Machine. You can force software rendering, but that's unfavourable on real machines.

My final choice was OpenGL and using SDL for cross-platform window creation and some additional functionality. OpenGL 1.1 is supported by (practically) all graphics drivers, and it even has out-of-box support on Windows even without hardware graphics, which especially matters on a virtual machine.

Some OpenGL functions were removed from 3.0, and in theory these could not be supported by a graphics driver, but any sane driver do support them for practical reasons, and they will at least for another decade. However, since the functions removed were due to performance issues, I did care not to use them when possible. The final drawing in the main loop is the sequence of `glTexSubImage2D` -> `glClear` -> `glDrawArrays`, all of which remain in the core profile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

// copy-pasted from a header-only stopwatch module

typedef struct {
  uint64_t before;
  uint64_t now;
} t_stopwatch;

static void stopwatch_start(t_stopwatch *s) {
  s->before = SDL_GetTicks64();
}

static uint64_t stopwatch_measure(t_stopwatch *s) {
  s->now = SDL_GetTicks64();
  return s->now - s->before;
}

static void stopwatch_startFromNow(t_stopwatch *s) {
  s->before = s->now;
}

#define WindowW 800
#define WindowH 600
#define FbW 320
#define FbH 240
#define FbTexW 0x200
#define FbTexH 0x100
static const float VertexCoord[] = {0, 0, FbTexW, 0, 0, FbTexH, FbTexW, FbTexH};
static const float TexCoord[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};

static void initGl() {
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
  glOrtho(0, FbW, FbH, 0, 1, -1);
  glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, FbTexW, FbTexH, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, VertexCoord);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, TexCoord);
}

static void resize(int w, int h) {
  int p = w * FbH;
  int q = h * FbW;
  if (p > q) {
    float w_ = (float)q / FbH;
    glViewport((int)roundf((w - w_) * 0.5f), 0, (int)roundf(w_), h);
  } else {
    float h_ = (float)p / FbW;
    glViewport(0, (int)roundf((h - h_) * 0.5f), w, (int)roundf(h_));
  }
}

static void draw() {

  /* Framebuffer filling is just an example.
     It creates an interesting image.
     The code only works on a little-endian machine,
     but just to make the formula look simple. */

  float t = SDL_GetTicks() * 0x1p-4f; // smaller multiplier -> faster animation
  uint32_t fb[FbTexH * FbTexW];
  for (int i = 0; i < FbH; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < FbW; ++j) {
      fb[i * FbTexW + j] = (int)((i + t) * (j + t)) | 0xff000000;
    }
  }
  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, FbTexW, FbTexH, GL_BGRA_EXT,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, fb);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc, (void)argv; // Windows SDL can't handle main(void)
  assert(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO));
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
  SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WindowW, WindowH,
    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  assert(win);
  SDL_GLContext gl = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);
  assert(gl);
  initGl();
  int fps = 0;
  t_stopwatch fpsWatch;
  stopwatch_start(&fpsWatch);
  for (;;) {
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      switch (event.type) {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gl);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
      case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
        if (event.window.event != SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
          int w, h;
          SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize(win, &w, &h);
          resize(w, h);
        }
      }
    }
    draw();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
    ++fps;
    if (stopwatch_measure(&fpsWatch) >= 1000) {
      printf("FPS %d\n", fps);
      fps = 0;
      stopwatch_startFromNow(&fpsWatch);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Interesting images

These are some images that the simple formula `(i + t) * (j + t)` produces. If there is a name for this kind of pattern or if you know the math behind it, some brief explanation would be very interesting.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: _If there is a name for this kind of pattern or if you know the math behind it_ - [Moiré Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). I used to generate these in highschool for fun.

Comment: @Reinderien Yeah, the pixelated curves make a similar pattern to those on the wikipedia page, but I think there's some more going on. See [this](https://imgur.com/a/VlLUki8) for example, when `t = 32512`.

Comment: I mean... "more going on" is kind of a stretch; it isn't that complicated. Mathematically this is three superposed R3 surfaces, one per colour channel, with all dimensions non-negative discrete and the last dimension subject to modular congruence (mod 256). It's still a Moiré pattern, and the modular congruence is what produces this pattern. You could somewhat easily calculate the functions defining band edges of the pattern by solving for places where the surface (mod 256) == 0.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks, I currently cannot understand all what you're saying, but I think I'll come back to your comment some time later.